# Storing Data From WinForms App in .Txt file

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a very basic C# WinForms application to generate random numbers. The code is shown below:

```
private static double RandomNumber(double min, double max)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    var next = random.NextDouble();
    return min +(next * (max - min));
}

private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var maxNum = Convert.ToDouble(txbInput.Text);
    var randomDec = Math.Round(RandomNumber(0, maxNum), 2);
    txbResult.Text = randomDec.ToString();
}
```

Now what I want do be able to do is on the button click save the random number that is generated in a locally saved file, along with a timestamp.

I am fairly new to C# and have a limited knowledge on how to do this. Therefore any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Don't create the random instance in the method but reuse a field, otherwise you'll get repeating numbers if the method is called in a loop.

Comment: Doubt it, since I think they get a different seed ... (or should otherwise ...). I agree the random should be reused though :)

Comment: Since you're new to C#, some advice unrelated to the question: Use var less. It would be a bad habit to get into to use it all the time. It makes code much less readable.

Comment: Are you asking how to save the file?

Comment: @Noctis: The default constructor of `Random` derives the seed from the [current time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount(v=vs.110).aspx), if you call this method very fast(in a loop) you'll get repeating numbers since the seed is the same.

Comment: @TimSchmelter craporama !!! You're a 1000% right. Darn, that's silly ... (well, putting a loop that outputs randoms is silly to begin with, but you were right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These examples show various ways to write text to a file. The first two examples use static methods on the System.IO.File class to write either a complete array of strings or a complete string to a text file. Example #3 shows how to add text to a file when you have to process each line individually before writing to the file. Examples 1-3 all overwrite all existing content in the file. Example #4 shows how to append text to an existing file.

```
class WriteTextFile
{
    static void Main()
    {

        // These examples assume a "C:\Users\Public\TestFolder" folder on your machine.
        // You can modify the path if necessary. 

        // Example #1: Write an array of strings to a file. 
        // Create a string array that consists of three lines. 
        string[] lines = { "First line", "Second line", "Third line" };
        // WriteAllLines creates a file, writes a collection of strings to the file, 
        // and then closes the file.
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines.txt", lines);


        // Example #2: Write one string to a text file. 
        string text = "A class is the most powerful data type in C#. Like a structure, " +
                       "a class defines the data and behavior of the data type. ";
        // WriteAllText creates a file, writes the specified string to the file, 
        // and then closes the file.
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteText.txt", text);

        // Example #3: Write only some strings in an array to a file. 
        // The using statement automatically closes the stream and calls  
        // IDisposable.Dispose on the stream object. 
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2.txt"))
        {
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                // If the line doesn't contain the word 'Second', write the line to the file. 
                if (!line.Contains("Second"))
                {
                    file.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }

        // Example #4: Append new text to an existing file. 
        // The using statement automatically closes the stream and calls  
        // IDisposable.Dispose on the stream object. 
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2.txt", true))
        {
            file.WriteLine("Fourth line");
        }
    }
}
 //Output (to WriteLines.txt): 
 //   First line 
 //   Second line 
 //   Third line 

 //Output (to WriteText.txt): 
 //   A class is the most powerful data type in C#. Like a structure, a class defines the data and behavior of the data type. 

 //Output to WriteLines2.txt after Example #3: 
 //   First line 
 //   Third line 

 //Output to WriteLines2.txt after Example #4: 
 //   First line 
 //   Third line 
 //   Fourth line
```

Reference from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8bh11f1k.aspx)

Comment: So, you copied it from my post, eh ? ;)

Comment: @Noctis Not from your post. Its from MSDN.

Comment: Teasing you mate ...I've posted the same link and example 2 minutes ahead of you ... that's all ...  :)

Comment: I am not teasing. i am not seen your answer till you ask the question.

Answer (score 0):

From the wise words of MSDN:

```
// Example #2: Write one string to a text file. 
string text = "A class is the most powerful data type in C#. Like a structure, " +
               "a class defines the data and behavior of the data type. ";
// WriteAllText creates a file, writes the specified string to the file, 
// and then closes the file.
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteText.txt", text);
```

Please refer to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/8bh11f1k.aspx) for more details and examples.

**Edit:**
Mine's missing the time stamp, but there are plenty of worthy answers here that add it :)

Answer (score 0):

To save your text to a file you need to use the IO namespace:

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Test.txt", txbResult && DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

This stuff show you how to write a string value to a file.

EDIT: Added the timestamp value.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void WriteData(double value)
{
    using (var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\file.txt", true))
    {
        file.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", value, DateTime.Now));
    }
}
```

You can see this link [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/8bh11f1k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Get the time - DateTime.Now.

Answer (score 0):

add this:

`// using System.IO;

    string filepath = @"C:\test.txt"; //sample file name & location

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filepath))

    {

    writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + randomDec.ToString());

    } // write your text in a string`